# Definition of surjectivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A function $f$ with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$ is said to be surjective, if:

$ \forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X, \space y=f(x)  $

How can I write this definition using material implications? Considering $f[X]$ the image of $f$, defined as $f[X] = \{  \forall z \in Y : \exists x \in X : z=f(x)\}$, then surjectivity is defined as 
$Y \subset f[X]$, which is equivalent to $\forall y [y \in Y \rightarrow y \in f[X] ]$. From here on, I am unsure how to proceed. $y \in f[X]$ seems to be the same of $y \in Y \wedge \exists x \in X (y=f(x)) $. The equality $y=f(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall z[z \in y \leftrightarrow z \in f(x)]$, thus:

$\forall y [y \in Y \rightarrow y \in Y \wedge \exists x \in X [\forall z[z \in y \leftrightarrow z \in f(x)] ] ]$

Is that somewhat correct?

Answer (score 1):

The material implication is $( not\; p)\; \vee \;q $ instead of $  p \implies q$.

thus, the classical definition of sujectivity which is

$$(\forall y\in \mathcal{U})$$
$$ \Bigl(y\in Y \implies (\exists x\in X)\; :\; f(x)=y\Bigr)$$

becomes

$$(\forall y\in \mathcal{U})\;$$
$$ \Bigl(y\notin Y\;  \vee \; (\exists x\in X)\; : \; f(x)=y\Bigr)$$

Comment: So, Mr. Abdallah, $ \forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X, \space y=f(x)  $   is indeed equivalent to $\forall y [y \in Y \rightarrow y \in Y \wedge \exists x \in X : f(x)=y ]$  ?

Comment: you can also use the universal set $ \mathcal{U}$ which contains the set $Y$.